# how to fulfill a parameter that passed by reference in c++?

Tags: c++, parameters

I've created a method which is accept parameter by reference like following :

```
void Func1(QList<int> *a){
 (*a) << getDataFromAnotherFunction();
//or
(*a).append(getDataFromAnotherFunction());
}

QList<int> getDataFromAnotherFunction(){

//we will do something good over here

return QList<int>
}
```

but the problme is when I want to use the a's data there is no data in it.
and it says 0;
say I want to count the element in it like following :

```
//for passing a to func1 I use something like that
//QList a;
//func(&a);
//after retruning from func1 now I want to use the result like  below :

a.size();

//but the answer is 0
```

how should I pass my parameter to get the correct data?

regards.

Comment: Post real code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Looks like it should work, assuming that `Func1`, `func1` and `func` are all the same function.

Comment: This part of your code should work fine so give us bigger part of your code and please fix names etc because is a little bit confusing

Comment: Agreed, I don't see anything wrong with the code shown here. Are you sure getDataFromAnotherFunction() returns something? Post more code, try using a debugger

Comment: thanks for all of your answers . as you've told me my snippet doesn't have any problem.
actually I'm using QT slot/signal and now I understand that the problem is with slot/signal not the way of passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do like the following:

```
void Func1(QList<int> &a){  // this is pass-by-reference
a << getDataFromAnotherFunction(); 
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
QList <int> my_qlist;
Func1(my_qlist);
```

Note that you must overload the << operator. Your current behaviour depends, from what you have written, on the fact that in getDataFromAnotherFunction you are returning an empty QList.

Comment: Both methods are correct - pointer is good as well as reference. It won't be his problem

Comment: @Gaim: of course, but writing explicitly in term of references seems clearer to me, and clearer code is easier to write and debug. From the example I thought that the issue was with the getDataFromAnotherFunction returning wrong data.